Is there a way to issue writable callback without using lws_cancel_service_pt?
Using lws_cancel_service_pt to generate immediate interrupt to wake up the event loop causes very high cpu usage.
I have been using libwebsockets library for a while now version is 4.3.
https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets.
Using lws_cancel_service_pt to generate immediate interrupt to wake up the event loop causes very high cpu usage.
The program sends around 200 events per second to the server.
Events are added to the ring buffer as soon as they are generated.
Expected behaviour is :
LWS_CALLBACK_EVENT_WAIT_CANCELLED should be generated as soon as the event is ready to be sent and event should be sent to the server immediately.
Observed behaviour is :
LWS_CALLBACK_EVENT_WAIT_CANCELLED callback is called around 1/10 times of the events generated, due to which events are still in the ring buffer queue.
If lws_cancel_service_pt() is used in a for loop (along with lws_service which is always used), the cpu usage is too high and keeps increasing although it is mentioned that it is a cheap call.
Without using lws_cancel_service_pt(), the cpu usage is normal.
Requirement is event should be sent as soon as it is added to queue as priority is server receives the event as soon as it is generated at client.
What am I doing wrong ? How can I achieve fast event rate (although achieved using lws_cancel_service_pt but causes high cpu usage) ?
All the help would be appreciated.
